# What is the difference between .Any(s => s.Contains) and .Contains?

Tags: c#

I've realized that in some old code that I've written in C#, when comparing the occurrence of a string in an array that I've done it like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < NounsA.Count; i++)
{
    if (NounsB.Any(s => s.Contains(NounsA[i])))
    {
        --do something--
```

Where NounsA and NounsB are arrays of words.

I've now just done this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < NounsA.Count; i++)
{
    if (NounsB.Contains(NounsA[i]))
    {
        --do something--
```

I've compared the two and they return different values, so what I'm asking is, what does the first one even do?

Comment: This is basically an intersection.

Comment: The first one uses `String.Contains` rather than a container's `Contains`. So you're asking if there are any nouns in `NounsB` such that `NounsA[i]` is contained in that noun, which is of course different from asking if `NounsB` contains `NounsA[i]` as an individual element somwhere.

Comment: @Sinatr - Please re-read this question - it is not a duplicate of the question you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this code:

```
var NounsA = new List<string>() { "a", "b" };
var NounsB = new List<string>() { "aa", "bb" };

{
    for (var i = 0; i < NounsA.Count; i++)
    {
        if (NounsB.Any(s => s.Contains(NounsA[i])))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("!");
        }
    }
}   

{
    for (var i = 0; i < NounsA.Count; i++)
    {
        if (NounsB.Contains(NounsA[i]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("#");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it I get the following output to the console:

```
!
!
```

Both blocks are running through the `NounsA` list, one element at a time, and asking the following questions respectively:

1. Do any of the strings in `NounsB` contain **as a substring** the current value from `NounsA`?
2. Do any of the strings in `NounsB` **equal exactly** the current value from `NounsA`?

So in my example the first matches twice as `"aa"` contains `"a"` and `"bb"` contains `"b"`, but the second does not match because neither `"aa"` nor `"bb"` equals either of `"a"` or `"b"`.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for, I'm surprised that such a mistake didn't impact my project too much, thank you.